# How to use Java Script in Excel macros?

Tags: javascript, excel

I am not a programmer and have a very very limited knowledge about both VB coding and Java scripting.
I have a software which can be currently run through a Java script. The software does some caluculations and saves the result file in a folder.
I just want an example of Excel macros which could run this Java script, this way I wont have to physically go into the software to run it and would be done in excel by click of a button. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Noman Aziz

Comment: I'm confused... do you mean you have a Java problem or a JavaScript problem?  Despite the superficial similarities of their names, the Java and JavaScript languages are completely different.

Comment: I think he wants a VBA macro inside the excel (called by a button) but he was confused.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful:

1. [Running a Javascript from VBA](http://www.codetoad.com/forum/18_24565.asp).
2. [Call javascript function from vba](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/572176b3-48c8-4a6a-b473-4cf4e2acf256)
3. SO question: [How to call a javascript file via Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341112/how-to-call-a-javascript-file-js-via-excel-vba)